# Is there any way to get terraform ignore_changes working for specific map properties?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is there any way to get ignore_changes working for map properties,
eg a specific aws tag?

I can currently use:

`ignore_changes= ["tags"]`

to ignore changes on all tags but i am not sure how to ignore  a specific one.

In my case I have a timestamp tag that shouldn't trigger updates but should be updated if the resource gets recreated/updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that right now. See the following

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6632